# Handling data truncation in Talend

Tags: sql-server, excel, talend

I am copying data from Excel sheet to the SQL server tables.
In some of the sheets I have data bigger in size of the Table's schema in SQL.

i.e. Table's column has data type nvarchar(50) where as my Excel sheet has data of more than 50 characters in some of the shells.

Now while copying, the rows which has such data are not being inserted in to the database. Instead I would like to insert rows with such data by truncating extra characters. How do I do this?

Comment: `try ignoring error in talend` this should do it!

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114 Ignoring the error will allow the job to continue but none of the batch (even the good rows in the batch) will be written to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Java's substring method with a check to the length of the string with something like:

```
row1.foobar.length() > 50 ? row1.foobar.substring(0,50) : row1.foobar
```

This uses Java's [String length method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) to test to see if it's longer than 50. If it is then it uses the [substring method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to get the characters between 0 and 50 (so the first 50 characters) and if it's not then it returns the whole string.

If you pop this in a tMap or a tJavaRow then you should be able to limit strings to 50 characters (or whatever you want with some tweaking):

[image: Example of using the s.substring() method in a tMap]

If you'd prefer to remove any rows not compliant with your database schema then you should define your job's schema to match the database schema and then use a [tSchemaComplianceCheck](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tSchemaComplianceCheck) component to filter out the rows that don't match that schema.

Comment: I'd go with the SchemaComplianceCheck

Comment: It serves a different purpose. If you don't want any of a batch to hit the database if things are too long or the wrong data type then let it fail and then reprofile your source data. However if you want all your good rows to go to the database and then deal with the remaining rows separately then the tSchemaComplianceCheck is the way to go. And finally if you just want the data to hit the database and don't care about truncating some columns then by all means substring it. I'd be inclined to go with a combination of the first and second and only substring things in rare circumstances.